# How to copy and rename a file from one folder to another using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to copy and rename a copied file. The file extension is ".ini". I have multiple folders (Banks) with years 1985-2007. Each of these folders (1985-2007) contains cfgfiles folder that contains an ini file which I want to copy and paste it into Russell ->1985-2007 folder -> cfgfiles.

My code:

```
Function RenameMoveFile($oldlocationPath, $newlocationPath, $oldfileName, $newfileName, $Point, $year, $extension)
{

        $old = $oldlocationPath + $oldfileName + "_" + $Point + "_" + $year + $extension
        $new = $newlocationPath + $newfileName + "_" + $Point + "_" + $year + $extension
        copy-Item $old
        Rename-Item $old $new
}
$year = 1985..2007
Foreach ($i in $year)

       {
        RenameMoveFile -oldlocationPath "C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\1_Banks\Point1\$i\cfgfiles\" -                             newlocationPath "C:\SNOWPACK\Samarth\10_Russell\Point1\$i\cfgfiles\" 
-oldfileName "Banks" -newfileName "Russell" -Point "P1" -$year "$i" -extension ".ini"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only recursively look though your folder recursively at the root you type into the code.

I hope that gets you started.  I don't understand the requirements for the rest of the question, however.

```
$looking_for = "*.ini" # extension looking for
$path_from = "" # root of search;
$path_to = "" # where to drop found files, wont retain folder heirarchy;
$all_files_in_dir = Get-ChildItem -path $path_from -recurse -Include  
$looking_for | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName};
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path_to # Create dest for you files
Foreach ($i in $year) { ## create your year folders
     $p = Join-Path $path_to $i
     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p
}
foreach( $i in $all_files_in_dir ) {
if ( $i -like $looking_for ) {
     Copy-Item $i $path_to
     if ( $? ) { # was last command succsesful?
          echo "$i copied to $path_to
     }
}
else {
    echo "ERROR: "
    throw $error[0].Exception
         }
     }
}
```